# Quantum entanglement with different particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-entanglement

I ve been searching for some techniques that are used to create quantum entangled pairs. I can see that almost all of them are related with photons and rarely electrons. Are there other methods that are used to create entangled pairs with different particles like protons, or may be bigger particles like alpha ..etc?

Comment: A lot of this experimentation happens in the field of quantum computing. The first successful one, I believe, was an entangling of mechanical modes in two ion pairs: Jost *et. al.* (2009) https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4779. Then all the way up to a whole cat of 3100 supercooled Rb-85 (IIRC, or 87?) atoms (2015): https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03056. The heavier, the easier. Also, alpha-particles with their integer spin won't entangle.